# Python gingerit module example does not work

Tags: python, json, nlp

I want to do a python script that is correcting spelling and grammar mistakes of a text.
I found the gigerit library but when I try to run the code from their documentation, I receive an ugly error.

This is the code:

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

text = 'The smelt of fliwers bring back memories.'

parser = GingerIt()
parser.parse(text)
```

And this is a part of the error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I also created another empty environment where I installed this library in order to avoid conflicts. But whatever I do, I can't manage to make this code run.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and fixed it with the following solution provided by MythicalMAxX on https://github.com/Azd325/gingerit/issues/24:

"It was cloudflare antibot which was blocking request.
So you all can fix it by importing cloudscraper
and replacing line 16
session = requests.Session()
TO
session = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
In gingerit.py"